java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.User.getCustomerId()" because the return value of "com.User.getCustomerId()" is null
I have the following Spring Data JPA repository.
@Query(value = """
      INSERT INTO users(id, customerId, locale) VALUES (:id, :customerId, :locale)                                                                                                                                                     
            """, nativeQuery = true)
  void create(@Param("id") Long id,
              @Param("customerId") String customerId,
              @Param("locale") String locale,

.........

profileRepository.create(
            profile.getId(),
            profile.getCustomerId(),
            profile.getLocale())

When I have empty getCustomerId I get error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.User.getCustomerId()" because the return value of "com.User.getCustomerId()" is null

How I allow the code to insert empty value and SQL query to insert NULL as a payload?

Your error message doesn't make sense. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Try change the getter in Profile class
String getCustomerId() {
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.customerId) ? this.customerId : StringUtils.EMPTY;
}


Thanks! Any possible way to shrink the code?

Definitely. Try use
return StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(this.customerId, StringUtils.EMPTY);
Additionaly you can make a static import for StringUtils

I get NPE when I make a check for inner Java object. Any idea how to solve this?

No need for StringUtils here - Objects.requireNonNullElse(T,T) should do.

Is it possible to check for nonNull of profile before making create call to repo
if(Objects.nonNull(profile) {
profileRepository.create(
profile.getId(),
profile.getCustomerId(),
profile.getLocale())
}

If the client code is not prepared to handle null, it's probably not prepared to handle "". The solution is not to change the return value, the solution is to change the client code.

If you’re using Java 8 or higher, you can utilize Optional to handle potential null values more gracefully.
String customerId = Optional.ofNullable(user.getCustomerId()).orElse(null);

This is just a complicated way of writing String customerId = user.getCustomerId().
